# How to `yarn link` a dist folder?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

Is there a way to do a `yarn link` to a dist or lib folder?

Here is my code structure:

```
/package-a
  - package.json
  - src/
    - ...
  - dist/
    - ...
```

If I do `cd dist && yarn link` and do `yarn link package-a` to another project, it links the `package-a` root folder and not the dist, making the import looks like this:

```
import fn from 'package-a/dist/fn';
```

instead of simply:

```
import fn from 'package-a/fn';
```

Any way to make this work aside from manually doing a symlink?

Answer (score 20):

`yarn link` will look for the folder where the `package.json` is in. So if you copy your package.json to your dist, it should work:

```
$ yarn unlink
$ cp package.json /dist
$ cd dist
$ yarn link
```

Answer (score 7):

Not direct answer on that question, but with yarn you also can specify a package as a local dependency and it will work just like link, but it won't require package.json to be in the `dist` folder.

Just specify in the project's `package.json` where you would do `yarn link foo`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "link: ../foo/dist"
}
```

Here I specified a relative path, yours could be whatever in local file system.

However the best way from my experience is to use [yalc](https://github.com/wclr/yalc).

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was to conditionally alias the imports if there's a symlink.

In my project I have dependency `package-a` that publishes on the root, while the local version (symlink) has the files to publish on `package-a/dist`

On my webpack config I have the following:

```
// Check if package is symlinked, i.e. symlink path exists
const isPackageASymlinked = fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../node_modules/package-a/dist"))

...

// on my webpack resolve
resolve: {
    alias: {
        ...(isPackageASymlinked && { "package-a": fs.realpathSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../node_modules/package-a/dist")} )
    },
    ...
}
```

This way it will conditionally add an alias when the symlink path exists.

A more generic, less ES6 version:

```
// package name -> node_modules symlink path
const SYMLINKED_DEP_PATHS = {
    "package-a": "package-a/dist"
}

const symlinkInternalAlias = () => _.reduce(SYMLINKED_DEP_PATHS, (acc, symlinkPath, package) => {
    const resolvedPath = path.resolve(__dirname, `../node_modules/${symlinkPath}`)
    if (fs.existsSync(resolvedPath)) {
        acc[package] = fs.realpathSync(resolvedPath)
    }

    return acc
}, {})

//and then just need to add to the alias

resolve: {
    alias: {
        ...symlinkInternalAlias()
    },
    ...
}
```

With this you don't have to change the imports and keep them as

```
import { something } from "package-a/anotherFile.js"
```